# Show $f$ has only one real root.

Tags: calculus

**Let $f(x) = \ln(x^2) - 1/x + k$, where $x \neq 0$ and $k \in \mathbb{R}$. Determine the value of $k$ so that $f$ has only one real root.**

Note that $f^{\prime}(x) = \dfrac{2x +1}{x^{2}}$. Then $f^{\prime} > 0$, if $x > -1/2$ and $f^{\prime} < 0$, if $x < -1/2$.

Comment: @user376343 Oh ok, thank you

Comment: You said "$f' > 0$ if $x > -1/2$".  But do not forget that the $x=0$ is a bad point for $f$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since $\lim_{x\to 0^+}f(x)=-\infty$ and $\lim_{x\to \infty}f(x)=\infty$ and $f$ is continuous on $(0,\infty)$, there is at least one positive root. (It is the only positive root, because $f'(x)>0$ for $x>0$). Further, $-\frac 12$ is a minimizer of $f$ on $(-\infty,0)$, there is no negative root if $f(-\frac 12)>0$. If $f(-\frac 12)<0$ there are two negative roots. If $-\frac12$ is a root, it is the only negative root. So, if $f(-\frac 12)>0$ there is exactly one real root.

Answer (score 0):

HINT.-It is clear that $f(x)$ always has a positive real root.

The function $f(x)=\ln(x^2)-1/x$ has a local minimum at the negative $x=-0.5$ and this extremum is $f(-0.5)\approx 0,614$. It is easy to verify that for all value of $k\gt0.614$ there are no negative roots, for $k=-0.614$ there is a double negative root and for $k\lt-0.614$ there are two negative roots.

Consequently $f(x)$ has only a real root for all $k\gt-0.614$ (approximative value).